# I'm working on a DFS of a directed graph, How do I get to a node without any edges pointed at it?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~hzhang/c31/ch09-probs.pdf

The problem is 9.2 in the PDF above. I am confused how I am to get to Node E because it only has edges pointed away from the node; None are pointed at Node E.
I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to traverse all nodes by DFS, You must iterate for each node, and check the node is accessed or not, and use the node to begin a DFS.

```
    procedure DFS(G,v):
      label v as discovered
      for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
          if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
              recursively call DFS(G,w)

    procedure traverse_by_DFS(G):
        for v in G:
            if v is dicovered:
                continue
            DFS(G, v)
```

Comment: So, My tree edges would go a>b>f>d>c, then I would make a recursive call to DFS(G,e) to get my final tree edge of e>a? After my first call of DFS I have encountered every vertex except e.

Comment: @KyleDenHartog If you want to traverse all nodes in a week connected graph, you must iterate all nodes and check accessed or not. There is a reference, https://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy583/reviewed_notes/dfs_dags.pdf

Comment: @KyleDenHartog DFS can be used to check that is  graph a strong connected graph or not. Just as your example, the node e has no in-edge, if  you start from other nodes, it will not access node e forever in one DFS.

Answer (score 0):

It's a trick question. You don't hit node E, because you are forced to start at node A. This is the effect being given a starting node that isn't the true root - the result is an incomplete traversal.